# convert string to value type

Tags: c#

How to convert string ref type to value type..

Comment: can we get a little more info please

Comment: string is ref type right. so i need to convert this to a value type..

Comment: any value type tat can store a string

Comment: And why do you need to convert it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? string is a constant reference type, I never had a problem with this and can't imagine that someone desperately needs something else.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a string value type in C#.

The `System.String` class is indeed a reference type.

Tell us what you are trying to accomplish, and we might be able to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: `Nullable<>` surely is a value type, but because of the `struct` type constraint it will only allow non-nullable value types as type parameter :)

Answer (score 2):

Since string is constant (every mutation results in a new instance), there is no need to handle strings as value types. **The actually behave the same as value types.** Even comparison operations (`Equals` and `==`) are based on the strings content, not on the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can only convert *boxed* values to value types.
`String` is *reference type* and it can't become *value type* because there's no such thing as boxing for reference types.